# Finding T4 text template class code

Tags: visual-studio, t4

T4 text templates can be used to generate not only code but also any kind of text with visual studio.

I've read blogs and tutorials about T4 and as far as I can understand, visual studio dynamically builds a class in the background, compiles and runs the code in that class to build the text output.

Is it possible to see the source code of that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way is to change the Custom Tool in the properties window when the template file is selected in Solution Explorer.

By default, it will be 'TextTemplatingFileGenerator'.

If you change the custom tool to 'TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor' you'll get the underlying template class instead of the template output generated into your project.

To be precise, this code won't be exactly the same as that which is run under the covers, but it will be very close.

If you need the absolute exact code, you should leave the custom tool alone, but set the debug="true" flag on your <#@ template #> directive.  This will then leave the generated code sitting around in a random named '.cs' or 'vb' file in your %TEMP% directory.  Just sort the directory by time and it should be up at the top.